# Latest compatible version for NPM and node

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am using nodist version **0.8.8** which is the latest one. By using this I installed latest node version **10.7.0** and latest NPM version **6.1.0**. I assured it by reading the following document.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Nw I surfed in Google to find whether NPM **6.2.0** is available? If it is I want to know the corresponding **node** version for it.

Comment: Use appropriate tags to get help. The question is tagged in angular but related to nodejs.

Comment: In that same link you posted, there is a search field in the table; if you type `6.2.0` it will show you `Node.js 10.8.0` and `Node.js 10.9.0`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nvm` which is node version manager

With `nvm` you have the option to install the latest `npm` compatible with your currently installed `node`

use this link to install `nvm`:

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Plus 1 for nvm but it doesn't come close to providing an answer to the original question.

Comment: Minus 1 because by virtue of having nodist in the question, they are using a windows pc. And nvm is for linux based systems.

Comment: @Alex perhaps it used to be that way but nvm isn't solely for linux nowadays. You can install it on a windows machine, too - it's even available through chocolatey :)

Answer (score 4):

Node.js and NPM versions aren't directly connected, otherwise they would have matching versions.

Semantic versioning assumes that minor versions don't introduce breaking changes:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
>
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>
> PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

This means that if NPM 6.1.0 works with Node 10.7.0, NPM 6.2.0 works with it, too.

Node version requirements are usually listed in [package.json `engines`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) section, which can be checked locally or in GitHub repository.

`npm` package.json doesn't contain this section, so actual Node version that is suitable for it has to be deduced.

`npm` code base currently uses ES6 but no higher. [Latest Node 6 release covers 99% of ES6 spec](https://node.green/), it's expected that NPM 6.2.0 is fully workable with Node 6.14 or higher. Generally, it's certain that latest *even* major version (Node 10, as of now) doesn't have problems with latest NPM release.

Answer (score 1):

Node and npm are independent tools. You can very well install different versions of either.
Use

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```

to get the latest npm installed with your node.

use `node -v` and `npm -v` to get respective version informations.

Comment: This is not a good solution, it will always install the latest npm, even if it's not compatible.

ex:I just tried this on Node 16/14/12, and it updated to 8.3.0, on Node 10, it also updated to 8.3.0, with the following warning

Unsupported engine for npm@8.3.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16"}

but it installed it anyway (and npm is broken now). So this is not installing the latest compatible one as requested.

Comment: Yep, this just failed my builds since the latest npm yields an EBADENGINE error on node v16.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:
for anyone trying to install either node or npm via local .rpm packages in an air gapped machine (like me) you can reconstruct the dependency via by looking at the rpm name, e.g.:

```
npm-6.14.14-1.14.17.5.1.module_el8.4.0+943+c5e11f0f.x86_64.rpm
```

Where 6.14.14 is the npm version and 14.17.5 is the compatible node version

Bear in mind that this dependency is stricter than the real compatibility between npm and node but must be satisfied to install via rpm.